# Scipy.fmin_bfgs passing to many arguments to function

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network, minimization

I am trying to program a neural network and was trying to minimize the cost function using scipy.optimize_bfgs() and after attempting to use this I get the error that "TypeError: cost() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given". Where are these four arguments coming from and how can I rectify this?
The cost function is defined by:

```
def cost(param,X,y):
    Theta1 = np.reshape(param[0:106950:1],(75,1426))
    Theta2 = np.reshape(param[106950:112650:1],(75,76))
    Theta3 = np.reshape(param[112650::1],(1,76))
    m = len(X)
    J = 0
    a1 = X
    z2 = np.dot(a1,np.transpose(Theta1))
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    a2 = np.concatenate((np.ones((len(a2),1)),a2),axis=1)
    z3 = np.dot(a2,Theta2.T)
    a3 = sigmoid(z3)
    a3 = np.concatenate((np.ones((len(a3),1)),a3),axis=1)
    z4 = np.dot(a3,Theta3.T)
    a4 = sigmoid(z4)
    h = a4
    ##Calculate cost
    J = np.sum(np.sum(np.multiply(-y,np.log(h)) - np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h))))/(2*m)
    theta1_reg[:,0] = 0
    theta2_reg[:,0] = 0
    theta3_reg[:,0] = 0
    Reg = (lamb/(2*m))*(np.sum(np.sum(np.square(theta1_reg)))+np.sum(np.sum(np.sqaure(theta2_reg)))+np.sum(np.sum(np.square(theta3_reg))))
    J = J + Reg
    return J
```

The gradient is then calculated with:

```
def grad(param,X,y):
    Theta1 = np.reshape(param[0:106950:1],(75,1426))
    Theta2 = np.reshape(param[106950:112650:1],(75,76))
    Theta3 = np.reshape(param[112650::1],(1,76))
    Theta1_grad = np.zeros(Theta1.shape)
    Theta2_grad = np.zeros(Theta2.shape)
    Theta3_grad = np.zeros(Theta3.shape)
    m = len(X)
    ##Forward propogation
    a1 = X
    z2 = np.dot(a1,np.transpose(Theta1))
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    a2 = np.concatenate((np.ones((len(a2),1)),a2),axis=1)
    z3 = np.dot(a2,Theta2.T)
    a3 = sigmoid(z3)
    a3 = np.concatenate((np.ones((len(a3),1)),a3),axis=1)
    z4 = np.dot(a3,Theta3.T)
    a4 = sigmoid(z4)
    h = a4  
    ##Backward propogation  
    d4 = a4 - y
    d3 = np.multiply(np.dot(d4,Theta3[:,1:]),sigmoidGradient(z3))
    d2 = np.multiply(np.dot(d3,Theta2[:,1:]),sigmoidGradient(z2)) ## or sigmoid(z2) .* ( 1 - sigmoid(z2))
    D1 = np.dot(d2.T,a1)
    D2 = np.dot(d3.T,a2)
    D3 = np.dot(d4.T,a3)
    ##Unregularized gradients
    Theta1_grad = (1/m)*D1 
    Theta2_grad = (1/m)*D2
    Theta3_grad = (1/m)*D3
    ##Regularize gradients
    theta1_reg = Theta1
    theta2_reg = Theta2
    theta3_reg = Theta3
    theta1_reg[:,0] = 0
    theta2_reg[:,0] = 0
    theta3_reg[:,0] = 0
    theta1_reg = (lamb/m)*theta1_reg
    theta2_reg = (lamb/m)*theta2_reg
    theta3_reg = (lamb/m)*theta3_reg
    Theta1_grad = Theta1_grad + theta1_reg
    Theta2_grad = Theta2_grad + theta2_reg
    Theta3_grad = Theta3_grad + theta3_reg
    ##Concatenate gradients
    grad = np.concatenate((Theta1_grad,Theta2_grad,Theta3_grad),axis=None)
    return grad
```

Other functions defined are

```
def sigmoid(z):
    sig = 1 / (1 + np.exp(z))
    return sig

def randInitializeWeights(l_in, l_out):
    epsilon = 0.12;
    W = np.random.rand(l_out, 1+l_in)*2*epsilon - epsilon;
    return W
def sigmoidGradient(z):
    g = np.multiply(sigmoid(z),(1-sigmoid(z)))
    return g
```

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
X = np.random.rand(479,1426)
y1 = np.zeros((frames,1))
y2 = np.ones((framesp,1)) 
y = np.concatenate((y1,y2),axis=0)
init_param = np.random.rand(112726,)
lamb = 0.5
scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(cost,fprime=grad,x0=init_param,args=(param,X,y))
```

Then the error appears.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed into the cost functions are the parameters, followed by the extra arguments. The parameters are chosen by the minimization function, the extra arguments are passed through.

When calling `fmin_bfgs`, only pass the extra arguments as `args`, not the actual parameters to optimize:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(..., args=(X,y))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It got past this error but now the error is "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (75,1426)". What array is it even trying to reshape @w-m

Comment: Look at the error backtrace, it will contain a note to the line in your script that causes the error. Even without posting that here I can see its about the first line of the cost function (given the reference to shape (75,1426)). So it's trying to reshape a `param` array that only has length 2, whereas in your example code `x0` has length 112726. Maybe you ran something else?

Comment: Thanks, sorry to be a pain but I realised my error but now after it seems to run it crashes because of a "MemoryError" but after running 'top' in the terminal it only uses 3% memory. @w-m

Comment: I can't help you with this little information. Please create a new question for that issue, where you a) reduce the code example to as few lines as possible (< 10) while still reproducing the problem and b) post the full error backtrace, not just the error type. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.